# query with API Parameters: “contains” filter with “and” operator

Tags: strapi

Good day to everyone.
I was trying to test Strapi API in one of my projects.

Case Example: user searches for people who know various languages. The user will enter the languages, and it should filter out the people who “contain” all the languages which were selected. Basically the result should be the people who have the languages selected as a subset of their languages array.

I tried to do it using “contains” and “and”. But this doesn’t give the desired result.It gives the result for "or". After spending hours on this, it would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance

```
_where[0][languages_contains]=1&_where[1][languages_contains]=2
```

Answer (score 0):

> _where[0][languages_in]=[1]&_where[1][languages_in]=[2]

this might work in your case